# Spring batch job fails with IllegalStateException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I have a spring batch job which reads from a database, let's say db1 which is read-only, and writes the results into another, let's say db2. Unfortunately, the job always fails with following exit message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@4e7095ac] bound to thread
```

This is the configuration of db1:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.test.hello.model.dto")
public class Db1DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="db1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db1-datasource")
    public DataSource buildPrimaryDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(db1_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(db1_USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(db1_PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(db1_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("db1DataSource") DataSource db1DataSource,
                                                                           @Qualifier("db1JpaProperties") Properties db1JpaProperties) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(db1DataSource);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test.hello.model.dto");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(db1JpaProperties);
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "db1JpaProperties")
    public Properties db1JpaProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", db1_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", db1_JPA_SHOW_SQL);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", db1_JPA_FORMAT_SQL);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", db1_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        return properties;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db1EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db1EntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

This is the configuration of db2:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager",
        basePackages = {
                "com.test.hello.model.entities",
                "com.test.hello.repository"})
public class Db2DatabaseConfiguration {


    @Bean(name="db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db2-datasource")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(db2_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(db2_USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(db2_PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(db2_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource db2DataSource,
                                                                          @Qualifier("db2JpaProperties") Properties db2JpaProperties) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(db2DataSource);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test.hello.model.entities");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(db2JpaProperties);
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2JpaProperties")
    public Properties db2JpaProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", db2_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", db2_JPA_SHOW_SQL);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", db2_JPA_FORMAT_SQL);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2dll.create_namespaces", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", db2_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Here is the Batch Job Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchJobConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource db2DataSource){
        super.setDataSource(db2DataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(6);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(6);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("step-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchJobExecutionListener batchJobExecutionListener() {
        return new BatchJobExecutionListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job readAndWriteJob() throws Exception {
        List<Flow> flows = Stream.of(step1(), step2(), step3())
                .map(step ->
                        new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow-" + step.getName())
                        .start(step)
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new JobBuilderFactory(createJobRepository())
                .get("readAndWriteJob")
                .start(new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitFlow")
                        .split(taskExecutor())
                        .add(flows.toArray(new Flow[flows.size()]))
                        .build())
                .end()
                .listener(batchJobExecutionListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<InputEntity, OutputEntity> chunk(100000)
                .reader(step1Reader)
                .processor(step1Processor)
                .writer(step1Writer)
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is an example reader:

```
@Component
public class Step1Reader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<InputEntity> {

    private static final String SELECT_QUERY =
            "SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_123";

    public Step1Reader (@Qualifier("db1DataSource") DataSource db1DataSource) {
        setDataSource(db1DataSource);
        setSql(SELECT_QUERY );
        setFetchSize(100000);
        setSaveState(true);
        setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(InputEntity.class));
    }
}
```

This is an example writer:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Step1Writer implements ItemWriter<OutputEntity>{

    @Autowired
    private OutputEntityRepository outputEntityRepository ;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void write(List<? extends OutputEntity> outputEntities) throws Exception {
        for (OutputEntity outputEntity: outputEntities) {
            outputEntityRepository .save(outputEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

I have tried adding @Transactional to the write method. I expect it to read the first chunk successfully continue with next chunk until all data is read and written into the database (job success)

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. `@Transactional` is not necessary on the `write` method, the writer is already invoked in the scope of a transaction driven by Spring Batch.